# Getting header with selenium-wire python

Tags: selenium, session-cookies

Need to get header from request with selenium wire. I'm taking cookie from header

```
    result_cookies = ""
    for request in self.browser.iter_requests():
        result = request.headers.get("cookie")
        if result:  
            if len(result_cookies) < len(result):
                result_cookies = result
```

But I have there different cookies, where userCategory=PU, and userCategory=LIM, how i can get cookie where userCategory is LIM.

Part of cookie:

g2usersessionid=e792fb427388bfbfd2f6d8c82163d763; G2JSESSIONID=A27799E20A8A42058502875CD1617C61-n1; userLang=en; visid_incap_242093=ivG0wNBcTX2qbGGfef/Kzsp15WAAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAALk1ZNmpA0m0hbUNh68t/9; incap_ses_260_242093=g/XKTK5T3TznIlAEpLSbA8p15WAAAAAALxw6bB7fGHsf1fHHG2AGPg==; userCategory=LIM; copartTimezonePref=%7B%22displayStr%22%3A%22CEST%22%2C%22offset%22%3A2%2C%22dst%22%3Atrue%2C%22windowsTz%22%3A%22Europe%2FBerlin%22%7D; timezone=Europe%2FBerlin;

Comment: Can you share the output of your code?

Answer (score 0):

This how  I make use of selenium-wire to get the cookie from the headers:

```
   for request in self.driver.requests:
        if request.response:
        print(
            request.url,
            request.response.status_code,
            request.response.headers['Content-Type'],
            request.response.headers['set-cookie']
        )
        if "ivc_id" in request.response.headers['set-cookie']:
            cookie=request.response.headers['set-cookie']
            print(cookie)
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm getting many different cookies from header, and i need take where userCategory=LIM in cookies

Comment: @lotexteam Can you check if these cookies are stored in the application storage of your Chrome browser?